# Dota2 - Commands similar to legacy Dota (like -st to elune acuracy hook acuracy etc)

Tags: dota-2

My question is: I wanted to see flesh heap stats and I typed -st to no avail, and then guessed that it would be -stats, but I could not find it. Is it available at all? Or it is already there exists and hidden somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flesh heap stats are floored (rounded down) to the nearest integer. You cannot use in game text commands in the chatbox like in the original dota, however there is an icon for flesh heap that displays when you have a level in the ability. A flesh heap bonus of zero will not show.

[image: Old interface, but the icon hasn't changed much since.]

There are icons for other heroes too, like Silencer's intelligence stolen, but I'm not sure what else you'd have in mind.

Answer (score 2):

So I had a look [here](http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Console_Command_List) which supossedly has all the console commands and I couldn't find anything similar to what you asked for. So, most probably it is not available YET, or maybe they implemented it but didn't update the wiki page(which was last modified 17 February 2012).

Sorry for the answer. Wish I could have given you some better news :)

As Decency suggested maybe you don't need a command line to find out what you need. If I find out anything else I will edit this ;)

Answer (score 2):

Flesh heap displays the count as a buff within your status bar after you've leveled the skill. Just look there; no commands needed.

Comment: @ Decency and @enche what about mirana's elune accuracy? nvms souls etc.? My question is about command similar to -st not just about flesh heap

Comment: @GeoStrike No idea on those, sorry.

Comment: @GeoStrike Nevermore souls are also counted like flesh heap. As for accuracy of arrows/hooks, not implemented.